# Find the percentage of inmates who will recidivate

Tags: statistics, percentages

I'm working on a paper and one of the texts states "On average, inmates who participated in correctional education programs had 43% lower odds of recidivating than those who did not...this translates into a reduction in the risk of recidivating of 13% for those who participate in correctional education programs versus those who do not"

Does this mean, an inmate who participates in an education program has a 13% percent chance to end up back in prison, and that for an inmate who does not participate in an educational program they would have a 66% chance of ending up back in prison (43% higher than someone in an educational program)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret the article as follows:

The chance of an inmate re-offending, who does not receive correctional education programs is $~X : 0 < X < 1.$

The chance of an inmate re-offending, who does receive correctional education programs is $~(1 - 0.43) \times X.$

$X - \left[(1 - 0.43) \times X\right] = 0.13.$

---

Assuming that I have interpreted the article correctly, this implies that 
$\displaystyle (0.43) \times X = 0.13 \implies X = \frac{13}{43}.$

This is the fraction of inmates who will re-offend if they do not receive correctional education programs.

Then, the fraction of inmates who will re-offend if they do receive correctional education programs is 
$\displaystyle (0.57) \times X = \frac{57 \times 13}{100 \times 43}.$

---

**Edit**
Is it just me, or does the $\displaystyle X = \frac{13}{43}$ fraction seem significantly too low.

Comment: There are three main possible cases: 1. Quite likely, the paper's author is not very mathematically literate, and means what the OP is suggesting. 2. Your interpretation is the intended one. 3. The author really does mean odds instead of probability, in which case said odds is $\frac X{1-X},$ in which case $X=\frac{13}{56}.$ Do you agree?

Comment: @ryang Yes, I think that you summarized it well.